# Stack a list of numpy arrays

Tags: python, arrays, list, numpy

I have a list of numpy arrays that are of the following shapes:

```
(16, 250, 2)
(7, 250, 2)
(1, 250, 2)
```

I'm trying to stack them all together so they are a single numpy array of shape :

```
(24, 250, 2)
```

I tried using np.stack but I get the error:

```
ValueError: all input arrays must have the same shape
```

Comment: Try `concatenate` with axis=0.

Comment: perfect, thank you very much.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The trick is to use the right stacking method, in your case since you are stacking vertically you should use [np.vstack](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.vstack.html)

```
import numpy as np

a = np.random.random((16, 250, 2))
b = np.random.random((7, 250, 2))
c = np.random.random((1, 250, 2))

arr = np.vstack((a,b,c))
arr.shape
(24, 250, 2)
```

Comment: this also works for my list, if i do arr = np.vstack(mylist)

Answer (score 2):

You can use np.concatenate: You will get this:-

```
a = np.random.rand(16,250,2)
b = np.random.rand(7,250,2)
c = np.random.rand(1,250,2)
print(np.shape(np.concatenate([a,b,c], axis=0))
```

Output:

```
(24,250,2)
```